# Issue when creating an installer using wix to install in a specific website(NOT in Default Web Site)

Tags: wix, .net-3.5, wix3

I am creating an .msi using wix to install in "Test Web Site". But it always installs in "Default web site". The .wxs looks like:

```
<iis:WebSite Id='WebSiteId' Description="Test Web Site" Directory="Test_dir" >
  <iis:WebAddress Id="TcpAddress" Port="80" />      
</iis:WebSite>

<iis:WebVirtualDir Id="VirtualDir" Alias="TestService" Directory="Test_dir" WebSite="WebSiteId" >
   <iis:WebApplication Id="TestWebApp" Name="TestService" />                
</iis:WebVirtualDir>
```

Does anyone know how to install into  "Test Web Site" (NOT in "Default Web Site")?

Comment: Hi,
I found the solution for the problem I mentioned. 
  <iis:WebSite Id='WebSiteId' Description="Test Web Site" Directory="Test_dir" SiteId="*" >
      <iis:WebAddress Id="TcpAddress" Port="80" />      
    </iis:WebSite>

When the attribute "SiteId" is set to "*", then the website lookup is done using the "Description" attribute of the "<iis:WebSite>" element. 

Thanks,
Menaka

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution for the problem I mentioned.

```
<iis:WebSite Id='WebSiteId' Description="Test Web Site" Directory="Test_dir" SiteId="*" > 
  <iis:WebAddress Id="TcpAddress" Port="80" />
</iis:WebSite>
```

When the attribute `SiteId` is set to `*`, then the website lookup is done using the `Description` attribute of the `<iis:WebSite>` element.

Comment: Although my problem was entirely different (we just wanted the default site, even if it wasn't called "Default Web Site" [for a different language version of Windows for example]), this answer still helped me. :)